# Rotate objects around a point

Tags: javascript, animation, 3d, rotation, geometry

I'm currently working on a 3d "cloud" which consists of some div elements. These div elements should rotate around a point. This works like a charme on the x-axis but i can't get it working on the y-axis too. I've put the important things into a jsfiddle project:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lggdq/19/

If you click and move with your mouse, the items are rotating. How can i get it to work on the y-axis (the items are moving but not as i want them to do)? The items should rotate like on the x-axis.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like you have it (I didn't dive too deep into the Math), but it looks like all you need to do is make the divs change their y position as well as zoom to give the desired effect. As it appears now you only have the zoom aspect working...

Comment: To clarify, as the mouse moves up/down, the divs zoom respectively to the mouse. The needed animation is to have the divs ALSO change their y position. So if the mouse motion is down, the divs should move down, zoom, and when they reach the bottom they should zoom out and move up. Sorry if I'm not clear

Comment: That's exactly what i want them to do ;) But i don't know how to calculate the x, y and z position of these elements (i must confess that the code for the calculation was written by someone else, i just modified it a bit to fit my needs).

Comment: Here is a good example of how I got it up with jquery... Dig in there and see if you can't find where your script is going wrong. I'm sorry I don't have the time to dig in with you =( [3d Tag Cloud - jQuery](http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/08/how-to-create-a-3d-tag-cloud-in-jquery/)